# Python pandas: filtering rows based on time criteria using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, filtering

I have a CSV file with millions of rows in the following format:

```
Amount,Price,Time
0.36,13924.98,2010-01-01 00:00:08
0.01,13900.09,2010-01-01 00:02:04
0.02,13907.59,2010-01-01 00:04:54
0.07,13907.59,2010-01-01 00:05:03
0.03,13925,2010-01-01 00:05:41
0.03,13920,2010-01-01 00:07:02
0.15,13910,2010-01-01 00:09:37
0.03,13909.99,2010-01-01 00:09:58
0.03,13909.99,2010-01-01 00:10:03
0.14,13909.99,2010-01-01 00:10:03
```

I want to first filer this data and then perform some calculation on the filtered data. I import it using pandas `data = pd.read_csv()`, to get a DataFrame.

I then transform the `Time` column to `TimeDelta` column (which I am not sure is necessary for what I want to do) where I write the time difference to the time `2010-01-01 00:00:00` by using

```
data['TimeDelta'] = pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_datetime(data.Date)-pd.Timedelta(days=14610))/np.timedelta64(1, 'm')
```

Here comes the part that I struggle with. I want a function that returns a new DataFrame, where I want only the first row after every `n` minutes, where `n` is an integer defined by the user.

For example. If `n=5`, the desired output of this function for my data would be:

```
Amount,Price,Time
0.36,13924.98,2010-01-01 00:00:08
0.07,13907.59,2010-01-01 00:05:03
0.03,13909.99,2010-01-01 00:10:03
```

And the output for `n=3` would be:

```
Amount,Price,Time
0.36,13924.98,2010-01-01 00:00:08
0.02,13907.59,2010-01-01 00:04:54
0.15,13910,2010-01-01 00:09:37
```

I have tried doing this using the `floor` and the remainder `%`, but being a beginner with Python I am unable to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
n=5
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = 'Time', freq=f'{n} min')).first()

                      Amount   Price
Time                                 
2010-01-01 00:00:00    0.36  13924.98
2010-01-01 00:05:00    0.07  13907.59
2010-01-01 00:10:00    0.03  13909.99
```

Comment: You could then add to this with the desired user input: `frequency = str(n) + ' min'` and then change your code to: `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = 'Time', freq=frequency)).first()`

Comment: @nixon, is there a way to avoid this extra line that appears? This seems to mess up the indexing of my columns, returning KeyError: 'Time'

Comment: The problem is, that now there seem to be 2 rows in the header, so if I say `newdf = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = 'Time', freq=f'{n} min')).first()` and then `print(newdata.Price)`, I get an output like `Time

2010-01-01 00:00:00    0.36`
And I cannot call the newdata.Date